# sync React Router’s props with a MobX Store

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I want to redirect when the sign up is failed in react.
And I am using Mobx.
So there is a question about this.
When I search for redirect, the people says that use the below code.

```
this.props.history.push("/");
```

this works when it is in the his own component.
But in my case, i am running that inside of action of mobx store.
And then, this.props is not the props of routes component. 
So I wonder how I can read history of route through mobx store.
Thank you so much!

```
// In the mobx store

 @action submitSignIn = () => {
    axios
      .post('auth/join', { email: this.initialState.register.email })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data === true) {
          this.props.history.push('/signin');
        }
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of going about it is to manually create a `history` object with the [`createBrowserHistory`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#usage) function from the `history` library, and give this object to the `history` prop of the [`Router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router) component.

Then you can use this `history` object wherever you like in your app to programmatically control the routing.

**Example**

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

class Store {
  // ...

  @action submitSignIn = () => {
    axios
      .post("auth/join", { email: this.initialState.register.email })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data === true) {
          history.push("/signin");
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Thanks to you, the url goes to the push url. But the other problem is although it goes to push url , the push url doesn't render. Just the url is changed without that url rendering.. could you help me more?? Maybe should I this at componentwillmount?

Comment: @DDDD Great! You're welcome. It's very hard to say what might be wrong in your app without seeing the code. Maybe you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and it would be easier to figure out what might be wrong.